# Input hidden value propery when value has spaces

Tags: jquery, python, html, bottle

I have a form with the hidden value holding onto the name of a question that is stored in a mysql database. The issue I am having is that the hidden value only holds onto the first part of the name. For example, in my template:

```
% for d in data
  <input type="hidden" name="question_name" value={{d["name"]}}>
% end
```

`d["name"]` would be something like "math question". When I checked the `question_name` value on the server, and the hidden input value in jQuery, the result is `math` and it leaves out anything coming after the first word. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with quotes other ways the remaining part is considered as another attribute of the tag.

```
% for d in data
  <input type="hidden" name="question_name" value="{{d["name"]}}">
% end
```